# How do I stop the cursor on my wireless mouse from periodically freezing for several seconds? It clicks fine

Tags: mouse, freeze, logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse

Problem: My wireless mouse cursor locks up for 5-10s, but not the buttons -- I still retain the ability to click.

Setup:

- Verbatim keyboard and mouse wireless duo (one receiver), with Verbatim mouse turned off.
- Logitech m310 mouse, which freezes. (I use this instead of the Verbatim because I find the Verbatim mouse too small for my hand.)
- I have the same keyboard/mouse setup on two different laptops - one with Windows 7 64-bit (at home) and the other with Windows 10 64-bit (at work). I use different anti-virus software on each computer (Avast on one, Norton on the other).

So the problem occurs on two different computers with two different m310 mice. It did not occur while I was using just the Verbatim mouse.

I tried uninstalling the Verbatim mouse in device manager, in case there was a conflict, but it reinstalled itself. I successfully disabled the Verbatim mouse, but the problem still happens about every 1-2 days. This may be less frequent than before, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Comment: Are they both laptops?

Comment: Yes -- I have the same keyboard/mouse setup on two different laptops.

Comment: See if this helps, it worked on my W10 laptop...https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3gtdvs/mouse_keeps_freezing_in_windows_10/

Comment: Could you specify which solution was of assistance? Note: I do not have a problem with either laptop's touchpad. Both touchpads still work fine, even when the problem is happening on the m310. Also, my m310 does not "lag" as described in that problem. The cursor doesn't catch-up with my movements when it kicks back in.

Comment: first answer by "OriginalUsername30" worked for me.

Comment: The solution is for touchpads, but I don't have problems with my touchpads. In case there is some relationship between my mouse issue and my touchpads, I have checked the box that says "Disable internal pointing device when external USB pointing device is attached." I'll post again if that helps.

Comment: Completely disabling the touchpad had no effect on my mouse's problematic behavior.

Comment: Sometime in the past few months, the problematic behavior stopped on both laptops. As I don't recall doing anything different on either laptop, I suspect it was resolved by a windows update.